# why scipy.optimize.curce fit function is not fitting the data points correctly and why giving large values of pfit?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares

In the following code why fitting function is giving large values of pfit and why it is not correctly fitting to the data points. Is there anything wrong in my fitting function ?

```
L = np.array([12,24,36,48])
Ec_L =np.array([-2.21173697, -2.01880398, -1.96508108, -2.0691906 ])

def ff(L,a,v,Ec):
    return (a*L**(-1.0/v))+Ec

x_data = 1.0/L
y_data = Ec_L

plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, marker='.', color='orange')

pfit,pcov = optimize.curve_fit(ff,x_data,y_data)
print("pfit: ",pfit)  #pfit:  [ 563.99154975 4377.13071157 -566.48046716]
print(pcov)

plt.plot(x_data, ff(L,*pfit), marker='.', color='red')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `L` in your test but `1/L` in your fitting; I don't know what you intent, but if you instead use

```
plt.plot(x_data, ff(1/L,*pfit), marker='.', color='red')
```

the fit looks less off:

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing out my mistake. Can you please explain why I need to choose 1/L ? I defined my fitting function with L so why in plt.plot (x_data,1/L)?

Comment: @huda_: I just used `1/L` because that's how you defined `x_data`; it would have been more apparent if I had just said `plt.plot(x_data, ff(x_data,*pfit), ...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be very well fit by a quadratic equation and appears to to lie on a parabola. Here is a graphical polynomial fitter using your data and a 2nd order polynomial equation, the polynomial order can be changed at the top of the code.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


L = [12,24,36,48]
Ec_L = [-2.21173697, -2.01880398, -1.96508108, -2.0691906 ]

# rename to match previous example code
xData = numpy.array(L, dtype=float)
yData = numpy.array(Ec_L, dtype=float)


polynomialOrder = 2 # example quadratic equation


# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(xData, yData, polynomialOrder)
print('Fitted Parameters:', fittedParameters)

# predict a single value
print('Single value prediction:', numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, 3.0))

# Use polyval to find model predictions
modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xData)
absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xModel)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_title('numpy polyfit() quadratic example') # add a title
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Quadratic equation is showing best fit to my data points. But in my fitting function I have a value 1/v that I need to find out by fitting function so how will i do by using Quadratic function?Moreover in my fitting function Ec is the intercept so what will be corresponding value in quadratic equation?

Comment: If you have a requirement for a "1/v" term in the equation, then a parabola is unsuitable as it does not meet that requirement.

Comment: the last question. In my fitting function Ec is the intercept of straing line. In quadratic fitting what will be Ec? Is is correct if I find Ec value from quadratic (because it is best fit) and then I inset that Ec value in my fitting function(having 1/v) and then I only use 1/v as fitting parameter? But then what is Ec in Quadratic?

Comment: I do not know enough about the problem context to answer, other than to say that one of the quadratic equation parameters is the value when x = 0, which is also true for a straight line equation.